# How to combine precision or rounding with d3.format

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to display a tooltip value that is rounded to two decimal places, with a "s" SI prefix and my own suffix "b" for displaying file size in Mb, kb etc. Here's a small sample of code:

```
svg.append("rect")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
    .on("mouseover", function() { focus.style("display", null); })
    .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
    .on("mousemove", mousemove);

     var bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.date; }).left;
         function mousemove() {
             var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
             i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
             d0 = data[i - 1],
             d1 = data[i],
             d = x0 - d0.date > d1.date - x0 ? d1 : d0;
             focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + (x(d.date) + margin.left) + "," + (y(d.value) + margin.top) + ")");
             focus.select("text").text(d3.format("s")(d.value) + "b");
             focus.select(".mouse-line").attr("y2", height - y(d.value));
}
```

Here's the result I am getting so far. 
[image]

Any way to fix that?

Comment: What's the problem that you're want to fix?

Comment: i want to round that number to two significant digits. so instead of 60.182528 i want to get 60.18Mb

Comment: Just as an FYI, I think you mean decimal places, not significant digits. Rounding to two significant digits would give you 60!

Comment: Yes, two decimal places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you haven't actually formatted to two decimal places as you require.

Try changing your format call to include the number of digits like so:

```
...d3.format(".2s")(d.value) ...
```

Comment: that's not working. when I round the value before it's fed into the d3.format("s"), it get's displayed as above with decimal places.

Comment: @konrad Alternatively, you could use `Math.round` to do your rounding. Since you want it to two decimal places, something like 
`var roundedDValue = Math.round(d.value * 100) / 100;` should work. Can you give that a try? if it works, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Rounding is not an issue here. let's say i start with a number 1000 when i pass it into the d3.format("s") i would get 1k back. When I get a number 1001 and pass that into it, it returns 1.001k ...how do I round that return value so that it;s 1.00k? So as you can see pre-rounding the value doesn't do me any good unless I round it to nearest 1000s.

Comment: Oh sorry, I must have misunderstood the question. I double checked the `d3-format` [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-format)... have you tried setting the significant digit specifier in your `d3.format("s")` call? Something like `d3.format(".2s")` if you want two significant digits.

Comment: Ah! That does the trick. I didn't know you can do it like that. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to update your answer I will mark it as the solution. Thanks!

Comment: @konrad will do!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147647/discussion-between-rageandqq-and-konrad).